# Big Query shuffle size limit

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery, matrix-factorization

I have the following error on BigQuery while trying to run a matrix factorization

> Per-customer shuffle size limit exceeded. Please wait and retry, or reduce the size of your model, change training data query less shuffle dependent.

```
create or replace model `my_model`
    options(
        model_type="matrix_factorization",
        feedback_type="implicit",
        user_col="user_id",
        item_col="professional_id",
        rating_col="contact_force_scaled",
        l2_reg=30,
        num_factors=200,
        max_iterations=5,
        min_rel_progress=0.01,
        data_split_method="no_split"
    ) as (
        select * from `my_dataset_scaled`
    );
```

I'm not sure I understand what it means and how I can fix it. Is my dataset is too large for matrix factorization ? My dataset has 45 412 383 rows and it is a simple user/item/rating matrix (with mostly empty values)

THe only known limitation I was able to see on BigQuery is [100 million for a single user ratings](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-matrix-factorization#known_limitations)

Comment: Hi @Cyril Duchon-Doris, how much bytes are you processing?

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar, my BI tools reports ~40 million rows with ~2GB of dataset size for the dataset used as input for the ML model, does that answer your question ? Or is the data processed by the model different, and if yes do you know where I can get it's actual size ?

Comment: Hi Cyril Duchon-Doris, can you check your quota limit?